# Cannot connect Access to SQL Server Linked Tables - error message loggingin

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-administration, linked-tables

I have a client for which I am setting up a new SQL Server Express and (on a different computer) connecting their Access front end to that SQL Server. I created an account on SQL Server, changed authentication to SQL Server. I am able to log on to that account with no issues locally (through SQL Server Management Studio) on the server itself, but when I go back to the client machine and try to create either an ODBC connection or connect directly in Linked Table manager, I get the error below. Looking at the error log in SQL Server I can see no failed logins.  In Access and/or ODBC I use Servername\SQLEXPRESS, choose SQL authentication and type in the username/password that I created. But it's still being stubborn.

I'm kind of at my wits end with this one. I checked to make sure that login is enabled, that the created database is mapped to this user, but I'm out of answers. Anyone have any ideas? I'm sure it's something really stupid that I'm overlooking, I've used SQL Server for a long time but I'm not an experienced DB Administrator I'm sure it's something really simple I'm overlooking, but I've done this hundreds of times before. And Windows Authentication won't work because it's on a different computer.

[image]

Comment: No Active Directory, to get Windows Authentication to work? Firewall configured (e.g. test [ping](https://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port) to Server:Sql-Server port). Sql Server Browser Service is running?

Comment: Thanks. Windows Authentication is just not an option here. I'm advised to use SQL authentication. Ping does work. I'll check the browser service. Would that be on the client PC?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/977528 may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to a named instance on SQL Server Express with `Servername\SQLEXPRESS`, you need:

1. SQL Server Browser service running,
   and its UDP port 1434 open in the firewall.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access

> **SQL Server Browser service**
>   **UDP port 1434**
>   The SQL Server Browser service listens for incoming connections to a named instance and provides the client the TCP port number that corresponds to that named instance.

2. The fixed TCP port for your instance open in the firewall.
   You set this in SQL Server Configuration Manager

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port

Comment: This turned out to be the correct answer, thanks! I turned on SQL Server Browser on the remote machine (and TCP/IP and cleared out the dynamic ports) and voila.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a network setting rather than server issue.

Check if all necessary permissions, configuration and settings on your machine running the server are OK to accept external connections.

Usually its the server that is rejecting the connection for security reasons.