# Can't connect MS Access front end to SQL Server back end

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-connection

I have imported data to SQL Server Express from MS Access and have tried to link to the data from an Access front end file.

I have tried several different login types, but each gives me the same error:

> Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Please help.

Comment: can you  connect using SQL studio? I would try that first.

Comment: Why would that be a better approach?  Please excuse my ignorance!

Comment: Well, in place of testing and playing with all kinds of code, DSN's, ODBC panel setup and a zillion other issues when trying to link a table? Might want to spend that 15 seconds trying to see if SSMS works, right?  If SSMS don't work, then it going to be a wild goose chase to get Access to work. About the only downside here is if you don't have SSMS installed on the same machine as you have Access, but then again you really can not work and play with Access + SQL server without having SSMS anyway, so that's rather a given, or at least it should be.

Comment: see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866825/cannot-connect-access-to-sql-server-linked-tables-error-message-loggingin

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a local instance of SQL server?

The default is usually YOURCOMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS.

But, you can use a "." (dot) in place of your computer name.
So, the server name should be  .\SQLEXPRESS

A few things:
When  you setup and attempt to connect? Always create a FILE dsn. The reasons for this are many, but one really nice reason is that then Access will by default create a DSN-LESS connection. This approach is preferred since then Access remembers the settings, and no external settings (such as registry or even a file (dsn) is used or required. And if you connect to a SQL server on your network? Well then you can distribute the access application to each workstation, and it will "just work" - all without you having to setup a DSN or do anything with the ODBC manager on each station. So, a great tip and habit. So, use a FILE dsn (and if you follow the default prompts when linking tables, a FILE dsn is the default anyway).

Next up:
Make sure the sql server browser service is running. In the past this was often not required, but now it is recommended. That service is this:

[image]

Once you sure that service is running?

Make sure that you enabled named Pipes - in fact I would also enable TCP/IP. That is found here:

[image]

Ok, now the next question:
Are you using SQL server logons, or Windows authentication?

For now since this is your local stand alone machine? lets go with windows.

As noted, if you have SSMS installed, then see if it can connect. This not only is a quick + easy fast test but it will also tend to give you the hints as to what the server name connect is. (this helps you when you attempt to connect with Access - you can see what worked with SSMS - and better is SSMS does usually figure out the correct computer name for you.

So, from Access, you now  choose from ribbon "External" data, and then import and link group - choose ODBC.

the wizard to connect will start.  choose "link to the data source".

At this point, the panels that start to launch are the same one you see if you try to use the ODBC manager from the control panel - but in most cases this road is better, since Access will correctly launch the x32 or x64 bit ODBC manager (it makes this correct decision for you).

So you be at a DSN name, but just hit new. Now you have to choose a ODBC (for sql server) driver.

[image]

For now, I would try  "SQL server". You can choose SQL Server Native Client 11 (or later if you see). Either one is fine. Just keep in future mind that SQL Server driver choice exists on all computers - so for future distribution to other workstations, this is a good choice. The native 11 (or later) driver is NOT installed by default, and you have to install this on other workstations if you want to use that driver if you move or distribute your application to other workstations.

Next, and now you can enter a name for this connection (myTestcon or whatever). Hit finish.

You should now see/be at this screen:

[image]

The dropdown for the server name SHOULD appear and work (it make take 30 seconds). So, it should show you a server name, and a sql instance.

Next, and now you have to choose the type of logon

Because this is a local stand alone computer? Well, you can choose windows logons, or sql logons. Being a local computer - choose the default - windows auth.

[image]

Next.

NOW VERY VERY important - make sure you change/select the correct database here - SO MANY skip or miss this - and that's painful!!

This one:

[image]

So make sure you select/change the default from "master" to your database you created when you sent the data to sql server.

Next - (you can try the test data source). "ok".

Now you are back to the VERY same starting panel. Your "name" should be defaulted for the file connection. This:

[image]

So, now just click ok.

You can then select the tables you want to link to.

Comment: Wow, that looks great. So, one step at a time.

I need to connect to SQL Server from client PCs in a LAN (initially) and then also from within a WAN using VPN.
I have installed SSMS on a client PC within the LAN and got this error:

Comment: Cannot connect to SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: I made sure that the SQL Server browser service is running, and I'm using Windows authentication.

Comment: Well, if it is a local copy of SSMS, then of course we are talking about the SAME computer as to where the SQL express is running. If you going to have OTHER computers connect to that instance of SQL server then MANY OTHER issues such as windows firewall has to be dealt with. The context here WAS the SAME computer. If you going to have other computers connect, then you not be using windows auth to connect unless you using a windows DOMAIN.  Question and context was the one computer you doing this on. If we are talking about other computers - then a VERY big different question and context.

Comment: Ok, I accept that. We have a company server running SQL Server Express.  I need all PCs within the LAN and also connecting via VPN to connect.  Sorry, I didn't know if made a big difference.  Could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Well, how did the data get migrated. Surly that process must have involved access connecting?  And surly it must have involved SQL studio? (SSMS). So somewhere along the the way, data was transferred to SQL server. Since this is a network, and since eventually a VPN will be involved? The you want to use SQL logons, and not windows authorizing. So, you need to create a "user" for that one database, and the you ALSO need to create a SQL logon. Once you verified that the logon works? then and ONLY then do you want to attempt connecting. I also strong suggest you use IP address for server name.

Comment: So, likely you need to configure the firewall on the server that is hosting SQL server (open up port 1433 to allow incoming connections for that server). So you can google how to open up ports for SQL server. And you likely want to google how to create BOTH a user (for your database) and then ALSO you  must create a SQL logon (both are required). Once you do all above, then the steps in this post to connect will be the same but in place of windows auth, you use SQL logons.  So, you need to open up the fire wall to allow connections to sql server, you need to create the sql user + logon

Comment: Ok.  Yes, I used SSMS on the SQL Server machine to import the data from an mdb file using the data import wizard, but my difficulty is connecting from Access.  I have found advice previously about opening up ports, which I've done, so I will try setting up a user (I think  I've done that) and also a SQL logon.  I presume that these are created via SSMS?