# Migrating MS Access 2013 DB to better work from home solution

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ms-access-2013

I have a number of MS Access databases that range from the simple to the fairly complex.  They exist as split databases on a shared drive on an on site LAN and the users all have accdr front ends to work with.

Until Covid 19 this worked quite well, now we all have to work from home.  While I expected some performance issues, I did not quite expect performance to take quite that much of a hit.  So I am looking for ways to migrate to something that will work well with everyone trying to work via a VPN.

An additional fly in the ointment is that there is no budget to work with and getting IT support is akin to summoning the great old ones (it's difficult and you are likely to die insane).

So I have begun to research some different options.  MS SQL Server has come up, but I don't know very much about how to implement it.  I do not have a dedicated machine to put this on.

I have looked at Sharepoint, but some of the stuff I have been reading makes it seem like this is not a great option as some of my queries are complicated and I have some pretty large tables (45k records, 100 fields per record)  In the most complex DB, I have to add several thousand records each day and run several update queries on the freshly added records.

MS Azure looks promising, but again I don't know if that will put me at odds with the malevolent IT gods.

I started looking at office 365 Power apps, but I don't need any mobile device support and it doesn't look like it has the Oomph I need.

Google and Duck Duck Go haven't thrown up anything usefull that I could find among the dross.  I'm certain what I need is out there, I just can't find it.  I have found that One drive is right out, and likewise Sharepoint for anything other than the simplest DB I have built.

What I am looking for is any solutions, articles, books or even papyrus scrolls and stone tablets that might get me pointed in the right direction.  Any Ideas?  Any other information you need?

Edit:  After so looking I have found that I may be able to get MS SQL server on a virtual server without angering the IT demons.  Azure as a solution is out unless I find a suitable sacrifice.  Any good places to look for information on how to use SQL server from a standing start?

Comment: I'm not sure what else you are looking for. The migration doc linked by Robert is exhaustive and looks good. When setting up SQL Server Express, trying to get it connectable can be a bit painful, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59869623/3820271), and delve into the linked documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Consider migrating the backend databases to SQL Server.  There's a SQL Server Migration Assistant that will do this for you.  Your frontend will contain links to the resulting SQL Server tables.

The last time I did this I got an immediate 2X performance improvement on a LAN.  Over a VPN, you should expect similar, possibly better, performance improvements.  Quite a good win for something so simple to do without having to do a full rewrite.  Don't expect miracles however; Access by nature is a very thick client.

You don't necessarily need a full-blown SQL Server; SQL Server Express should suffice, and you can run that on any machine on your LAN.  The download for SQL Server Express Edition can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads).

You can read up on the migration process [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/migrate-an-access-database-to-sql-server-7bac0438-498a-4f53-b17b-cc22fc42c979).

Comment: The OP may run into issues with SQL Server Express. Depending on the number of concurrent users they need to support.

Comment: If he's running that many users already on a shared Access application, s(he) has larger problems.  Migration might actually be an improvement; the app I upsized was comfortably capable of handling 20 concurrent users.

Comment: A cursory check for number of simultaneous users for SQL Server Express appears to cap it at 10.  It's not a limitation of SQL Server Express, but of the Windows 10 Operating System (Windows 7 allowed 20 concurrent connections).

Comment: I was unable to find any info on concurrent users either. That used to be a limitation of Express; perhaps it has been removed.

Comment: # of concurrent users is no problem with current versions of SQL Server Express. With a non-trivial application, some issues are bound to arise during the migration. Getting good performance will need implementing Pass-Through queries and Sql Server views to replace complicated Access queries that are run on the client. Nevertheless, this is the way to go. It will give better performance and other benefits, even if everyone is back in the office.

Comment: Well, I only have about 8 users TOTAL so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Unfortunately I'm getting no resources to actually set up SQL server.  I apparently have not made the required sacrifices to the great old ones.  Oh well.  Just have to find another way to boost performance.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [Remote Destop Connection](https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-connect-remotely-in-windows-10/) first!

As you already managed to connect employees by VPN to LAN, you just need to enable remote access to their machines at work! That is the simplest solution and it doesn't need a fast connection or any changes on the application. You can enable [WOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) so they can turn on machines themselfes.

Of course you should also consider migrate to a RDBMS like Robert advised!

Comment: Well, the Users do not have a separate machine to use on-site.  at best they have a docking station.  They have taken their laptops to work from home.  We are already working on at least getting me remote access to an on-site machine so I can do the really heavy maintenance.  the difficulties in getting through the bureaucracy is what is leading me to all the comparisons of our IT people to Cthulu.

Comment: Assumed small company without IT. Why is there no plan to setup remote access as crisis didn't start yesterday. If company wants employees to work from home, they have to provide the tools (like RDS or Citrix). Btw, IT department is not the enemy (they are responsible for IT services to work), but communication can be difficult, as users don't understand IT concerns and vice versa.  [Tips for Improving Communication with Your IT Department](https://inpublicsafety.com/2019/08/tips-for-improving-communication-with-your-it-department/), especially notice "explain your needs and not what you want"

Comment: It's actually a pretty large company, but they have, over the years, gutted the IT department to the point where it seems like they don't really have one.  All decisions are made in another country, all front points of contact are in yet another country with a host of language barriers, and our point of contact is usually first level tech support (Have you tried turning it off and turning it back on again) unless and until you can get the issue elevated.  Our company was set up for remote access through a VPN, but that was with Excel and powerpoint, not actual heavy data in mind.